# Deleting file from Parse.com usung REST API in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Why can't I delete a file from parse.com? Here is my method.

```
            URL url = new URL("https://api.parse.com/1/files/"+ parseFileName);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty ("X-Parse-Master-Key",      Sett.PARSE_MASTER_KEY);
            conn.setRequestProperty ("X-Parse-Application-Id",  Sett.PARSE_APP_ID);
            conn.setRequestProperty ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key",    Sett.PARSE_REST_KEY);
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type",            "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("DELETE");

            String responseStr  = conn.getResponseMessage();
            String responseCode = String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode());
```

`Result = 200 OK`, but the file is still available for download. Also, I tried to send a request through the control panel from Parse.com. Result was `null`

This is a link to file I triying to delete http://files.parsetfss.com/5592cbfd-6fd4-41ca-8a82-dd90ebcd6541/tfss-410de5c1-bbac-4772-8be5-45b4f55d47fd-1450985755273

Comment: did u tested in postman?

Comment: what is "parseFileName" ? And what value does it got?

Comment: parseFileName = tfss-410de5c1-bbac-4772-8be5-45b4f55d47fd-1450985755273

Comment: Ok. Well, I'm waiting for answer to this as well. I have the exact same problem as you, except I use Cloud Code.

Comment: @Benni. My problem solved. I don't know how exactly I did that. But try delete row which contains your file, and after that delete your file.

Comment: Ah.. well I want my user's to delete their files on a button-click, not me :p Or do you mean you just had to recreate the Row for the delete method to work?

Comment: @Benni. I meant that before deleting the file you must to delete the association with this file. As I understand you have uploaded file and it is tied to the some user? Take away the anchor to the file and then the file itself. Sorry for bad English)

Comment: @XXX I see. So it's not possible to let the user delete the file completely? I have to interfere in the Parse console? Or can i delete the association on Cloud Code aswell? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Benni. No need Parse console. You can do it programmatically through your cloud code. 1) Take away the association with the file. For this delete Parse object (row in the table) by objectID (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#objects-deleting-objects). 2) Then delete the file using a master key. Use REST API (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#files-deleting-files)

Comment: @XXX thank you! I think I'll sort it out now! :) Finally.